# How to start developing server and client side of simple chat application in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client, long-polling

I'm developing single page one room chat application : client side in `HTML`, `CSS`, native `JavaScript` and `AJAX` ; server side in `node.js`  and real-time updates with `long polling`, with `RESTful API`. I've already made the client interface with HTML and CSS , now I want to make the connection with the server. also in the client side I use `localStorage` .So for example ,when some user sign in , I save his details in a `localStorage` variable, then I want to update the number of the connected users to the room and display it in some label on the interface, so if this user is the first one to sign in then the number of connected users is one ,if there is another X users who are logged in then the total number of connected users is X+1.That should be updated for all the connected users.

This is my first time developing such thing ,I've been reading articles about this since yesterday but I still don't know how to begin.What I learned that for starting a server I need to add this to `server.js` :

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.end("Hello world");
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running.');
```

taken from [here](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch3.html)

It's my last school project and I am very confused and don't know how to proceed.I really appreciate any help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Socket for Chat Application,
Ref: https://socket.io/demos/chat/

Open two window by clicking the above link and try chat

Comment: hi thank you for replying ,but I am allowed only by long polling